# Are Euler Diagrams a type of Venn Diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I understand that a Venn Diagram shows all possible relationships, whereas an Euler diagram shows only those relationships that actually exist. An Euler Diagram won't show an empty intersection between two sets, whereas a Venn Diagram will.

I've illustrated my query with... um... some sort of diagram. Okay, It's an Euler Diagram, because of that small blue circle in the lower left. But what if we took that out? Now, all possible logical relationships are shown, *and* each segment of the diagram is occupied.

Does the vesica piscis-ish shape contain Venn Diagrams, Euler Diagrams, both or neither? (I doubt it's "neither." Just wanted to include all logical possibilities.)

[image]

Comment: I think of Venn diagrams as a specialized type of Euler diagram but I have a strong Euler bias and would likely give him credit for creating the wind if I caught him breathing. You can change whether a function is injective, surjective or bijective just by trimming or expanding it's domain and codomain and this may be analogous, where inclusion or exclusion of some part would change it's properties.

Comment: Didn't Kronecker say, "God made the integers, all else is the work of Euler"?

Comment: Euler diagrams are correct, Venn diagrams are not always correct.

Comment: "Venn diagrams are a more restrictive form of Euler diagrams. A Venn diagram must contain all 2n logically possible zones of overlap between its n curves, representing all combinations of inclusion/exclusion of its constituent sets. Regions not part of the set are indicated by coloring them black, in contrast to Euler diagrams, where membership in the set is indicated by overlap as well as color." - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram